# Conditional expectation given reverse conditional density.

Tags: probability

X is distributed as Beta(alpha,beta)
Y/X (Y given X) is distributed as Bino(n,X)

Find E(X/Y)

I have no idea how to access the marginal of Y  which I would need to do Bayes.

I also suspect there is a clever solution which involves no integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bayes's rule,
$$f_{X \mid Y=y}(x) = \frac{f_X(x) P(Y=y \mid X=x)}{P(Y=y)}
= \frac{f_X(x) P(Y=y \mid X=x)}{\int_0^1 f_X(z) P(Y=y \mid X=z) \, dz}.$$
Since $f_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$ and $P(Y=y \mid X=x) = \binom{n}{y} x^y (1-x)^{n-y}$, we have
$$f_{X \mid Y=y}(x) = C x^{\alpha+y-1} (1-x)^{\beta+n-y-1}.$$
Thus the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha+y, \beta+(n-y))$. From here you can readily get $E[X \mid Y]$.

Comment: Downstairs of your second line looks like a cts analog of what I know as LOTP (Law of total probability). I was under the impression I need a countable partition to use this. Can you justify this further? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Muselive Indeed, see [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) (and note that the probability of an event $A$ can be viewed as expectations of the indicator random variable $1_A$).

Comment: Just to check;  P(Y=y)=E(1(Y=y))=E(E(Y=y)/X=x)= the integral you have downstairs?

Comment: @Muselive Yes, $P(Y=y) = E[1_{Y=y}] = E[E[1_{Y=y} \mid X]]$. The inner expectation is sometimes written as $P(Y=y \mid X)$.